# Where to find large survival dataset with at least one time dependent variable?

Tags: data-request, medical, finance, metadata, time-series

Looking for a large dataset for survival analysis where at least one of the variables is time-dependent.

For example, this a sample dataset:

```
    time status sex age year thickness ulcer
1     10      3   1  76 1972      6.76     1
2     30      3   1  56 1968      0.65     0
3     35      2   1  41 1977      1.34     0
4     99      3   0  71 1968      2.90     0
5    185      1   1  52 1965     12.08     1
```

Ideally, I would want the "thickness" time history progression for each element/row until event time.

I have had no luck to find such dataset thus far.